# SonarQube differential drill down views not pointing the right issue in the class

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

We are using SonarQube 4.5.1 community edition. For the new PMD issues we are using differential views.

1) During differential view, I am able to get the number of new issues identified in the code, let say 20 new issues. When I drill down those 20 issues to identify the line number of class, it shows all the issues of that class including old issues also.

Is there anyway we can drill down and view only the new issues during the differential view?

2) I also see this message in the drill down view:

```
For performance reasons, only the 3000 first lines will be displayed.
```

Is there an option to view all lines when there are more than 3000 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This is probably a question of which number you're clicking on to get to the drilldown. Make sure it's one with a plus beside it.

2) Newer versions got rid of this restriction & introduced an 'infini-scroll' in the code viewer. Your best bet here is to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.